# SSRS 2019 not able to setup URL Reservations with port 443

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

here is the setup i have  - Windows Server 2022 and SSRS 2019  i setup IIS and setup a test site using the SSL cert and that is working fine and since have disabled it

i am trying to setup SSRS 2019 to work with HTTPS and it doesn't want to work for me.. default without any HTTPS or SSL cert setup the portal works fine but once i setup the SSL cert and the URLS with port 443. i keep getting "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED "

and without HTTPS and only the HTTP url i get a

Service Unavailable

HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

also the log is showing this

ERROR: Error creating HTTP endpoint. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

also getting this

here is what i get when i try to reserve a SSL port 443 URL

Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException: An unknown error has occurred in the WMI Provider. Error Code 800700B7

---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.ThrowOnError(ManagementBaseObject mo)

at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.RSWmiAdmin.ReserveURL(String application, String url, ErrorCodes& errorCode)

at ReportServicesConfigUI.WMIProvider.RSReportServerAdmin.ReserveURL(UrlApplication app, String url, ErrorCodes& errorCode)

different ports work and i am able to add the URL.. tried manually adding URL in the reportserver.config file but not working